# Move "dont ask" list out of the "do ask" help page

Tags: feature-request, help-pages

A while ago, I noticed that the Help Center page, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) contained a long list of things that users shouldn't ask about. However, there is a different Help Center page that's supposed to be about what types of questions not to ask. 
[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

I wonder if that list of "don't ask" topics could be moved from the former Help Center page to the latter.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between "What **topics** shouldn't I ask about?" and "What **types of question** shouldn't I ask?"

The first covers the subject matter; the second the actual questions which are asked.

That's actually shown in the lists:

> - The meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus.
> - Proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified. See below for hints on checking existing texts.
> - Writing advice (see Writers.SE instead) or critique requests
> - "How to improve my English?" (this is not constructive anyway)
> - Translation and non-English languages — please see the translation tag info for details
> - Naming, including naming programming variables/classes
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
> - Jokes that do not rely on the English language

Those are topics which explicitly do not fall into the "What can I ask about?" valid subjects.

The other list covers questions which might be asked about valid topics, but...

> - every answer is equally valid
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers
> - there is no actual problem to be solved
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question
> - your question is just a rant in disguise

So no: the two lists are orthogonal and seem fine as they are.

Comment: You say "*There is a difference between "What topics shouldn't I ask about?" and "What types of question shouldn't I ask?"*" From the OP's question, I would suggest that that distinction has not been made clearly enough - perhaps retitling might help?